# Short description isn't working for delete selected (delete_selected.short_description isn't changing the name)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am currently trying to change the name of the "Delete Selected" admin action. I have already effectively override the default (so I can store some data before completely deleting it), but now I want to change the option from the vague "Deleted selected" to something more specific like "Deleted all selected registrations." Or, at least, for it to say, "Deleted selected registrations" like it did before I overwrote the function.

I have so far tried this:

```
delete_selected.short_description = 'Delete all selected registrations'
```

But the option is still "Deleted selected." Is there a way to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
"""
This overrides the defult deleted_selected because we want to gather the data from the registration and create a
DeletedRegistration object before we delete it.
"""
for registration in queryset:
    reg = registration.get_registrant()

    if registration.payment_delegation:
        delegate_name = registration.payment_delegation.name
        delegate_email = registration.payment_delegation.email
    else:
        delegate_name = None
        delegate_email = None

    registration_to_delete = DeletedRegistration.objects.create(
        registrant_name = reg.full_name(),
        registrant_email = reg.email,
        registrant_phone_num = reg.phone,
        delegate_name = delegate_name,
        delegate_email = delegate_email,
        # Filtering out people (with True) who couldn't participate in events because we are only interested in the people
        # we had to reserve space and prepare materials for.
        num_of_participants = registration.get_num_party_members(True),
        special_event = registration.sibs_event,
    )
    registration.delete()

delete_selected.short_description = 'Delete all selected registrations'
```

edit: just tried delete_selected.list_display that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have it in the function, so I just had to tab it back one space and it worked.

example:

```
def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset)
    code

delete_selected.short_description = "preferred name"
```

thanks.